# Why does a shear matrix work only with x-axis or y-axis invariance?

Tags: matrices, analytic-geometry

Why can't a typical shear matrix work for invariant oblique lines? I understand that shearing a plane figure in 2D is essentially the mapping of points proportional to their perpendicular distance from the invariant line, and that the shear matrix is multiplied with the coordinate matrix of a plane figure to shear it with an invariant line with a shear factor of $n$ where $n\in\mathbb{R}$. However, what I do not understand is that, why this general form of the shear matrix in the image attached below (I am not able to attach images to my post), does not work for oblique invariant lines.

Any help is appreciated, please!

Comment: You can have a shear that keeps invariant any other line passing through the origin. Just multiply the matrix that you have from the left by some matrix $P$ with determinant different from zero, and multiply from the right by $P^{-1}$.

Comment: Even though you can't directly attach images to your question, for now you can include a link to a picture, and a higher-reputation user can then put the actual picture in your question.